# Using unity without Bolt

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, but not to C#, so I would love to avoid using Bolt. I don't mind spending the extra time making sure that my animations are correct.

I am trying to get a gun to shoot (the animation part [aka recoil])
[image: Unity interface]
[image: Error message]

As you probably can see that there are no parameters (in the first image). In the parameter box (where it says list is empty in the animator window), I clicked on the '+' to create a new parameter trigger (called it "M1911SHOOT")
[image: Animator Parameters]

However it does resolve the *Parameter does not exist* error message but nothing happens afterwards

---

Here is my code

**M1911.cs**

```
public class M1911 : Weapons
{
    private const string IDLE = "M1911IDLE";
    private const string BASIC = "M1911SHOOT";
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        IDLEANIM = IDLE;
        BASICATKANIM = BASIC;
        weaponName = "Weapon";
        damage = 15;
        heavyDamage = 35;
        weight = 5;
        staminaCost = 5;
        range = 3.5f;
        atkDelay = .7f;
        type = WEAPONTYPE.MELEE;
        Init();
    }

}
```

**Weapons.cs**

```
public class Weapons : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected enum WEAPONTYPE
    {
        NONE,
        RANGED,
        MELEE
    }

    protected string weaponName;
    protected int damage;
    protected int heavyDamage;
    protected int weight;
    protected int staminaCost;
    protected float range;
    protected WEAPONTYPE type;
    protected bool isAtking;
    protected float atkDelay;
    
    protected string BASICATKANIM;
    protected string HEAVYATKANIM;
    protected string IDLEANIM;
    protected string CURRENTANIMATION;

    private Animator _animator;
    
    protected void Init()
    {
        CURRENTANIMATION = IDLEANIM;
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isAtking = false;
    }

    public int Attack()
    {
        if (!isAtking)
        {
            isAtking = true;
            ChangeAnimation(BASICATKANIM);
            return damage;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void AttackComplete()
    {
        isAtking = false;
    }

    public void ChangeAnimation(string newAnimationState)
    {
        if(newAnimationState == CURRENTANIMATION)
            return;

        if (isAtking)
        {
            CURRENTANIMATION = newAnimationState;
            Invoke("AttackComplete", atkDelay);
        }
        
        
        _animator.SetBool(BASICATKANIM, true);
        _animator.SetBool(IDLEANIM, false);
        CURRENTANIMATION = newAnimationState;
    }
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player : CharacterAttributes
{

    public Weapons weapon;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Init();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Attack();


    }

    void Move()
    {
        //Movement stuff
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        weapon.Attack();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might just be a bit confused about the animation states vs. parameters. In the screenshot, you attached you have the entry into the idle but then no other connections. The animation parameters are used to trigger stat changes in the animation state machine using transitions. If you add transitions between the idle and shoot depending on the parameters you set, they should transition when set in code. I can post a more detailed step by step if you need.

Comment: I might also recommend if you are going to have a lot of guns, and by the use of a generic weapon base class you will, you might want to look into [`AnimationOverrideControllers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatorOverrideController.html). It allows you to make a generic Animation that can be re-used as a template. If all of your guns will have an idle, shoot, etc. then it might be worth while.

Comment: I just had the wrong method in the Weapons.cs class. I'll look into the OverrideControllers. Thanks for the help.
Method: _animator.Play(BASICATKANIM)

Comment: @user123 why would you possibly use "Bolt" ?  it's utter crap, and nobody uses it.

Comment: @Fattie If you read the title, it says without Bolt. I didn't want to use Bolt nor do I ever want to.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong method in Weapon.cs

Needed
`_animator.Play(BASICATKANIM);`

instead of
`_animator.SetBool(IDLEANIM, false);`

I wanted to play an animation, not play around with the parameters for the animator